# Django Debug toolbar incorrectly shown with nginx

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

Using manage.py runserver my debug toolbar works correctly but when I use nginx my toolbar only shows "DEBUG" in the panel. I have all the static files linked correctly.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

**NGINX Conf**

This is the conf for my site, which gets included into my nginx.conf

```
upstream polonel {
# fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
# to return a good HTTP response (in case the Unicorn master nukes a
# single worker for timing out).

server unix:/home/chris/webapps/pyPolonel/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

listen   80;enter code here
server_name localhost;

client_max_body_size 4G;

access_log /home/chris/webapps/pyPolonel/logs/nginx-access.log;
error_log /home/chris/webapps/pyPolonel/logs/nginx-error.log;

location /static/ {
    alias   /home/chris/webapps/pyPolonel/static/;
}

location /media/ {
    alias   /home/chris/webapps/pyPolonel/Polonel/media/;
}

location / {
    # an HTTP header important enough to have its own Wikipedia entry:
    #   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    # enable this if and only if you use HTTPS, this helps Rack
    # set the proper protocol for doing redirects:
    # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    # pass the Host: header from the client right along so redirects
    # can be set properly within the Rack application
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
    # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
    proxy_redirect off;

    # set "proxy_buffering off" *only* for Rainbows! when doing
    # Comet/long-poll stuff.  It's also safe to set if you're
    # using only serving fast clients with Unicorn + nginx.
    # Otherwise you _want_ nginx to buffer responses to slow
    # clients, really.
    # proxy_buffering off;

    # Try to serve static files from nginx, no point in making an
    # *application* server like Unicorn/Rainbows! serve static files.
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        proxy_pass http://polonel;
        break;
    }
}

# Error pages
error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
location = /500.html {
    root /home/chris/webapps/pyPolonel/Polonel/static/;
}
}
```

Comment: Please show your nginx configuration.

Comment: I added the conf to the original post

Comment: Same problem here. As a temporary workaround I've been able to show the debug toolbar panels by adding: `from django.contrib import admin \ admin.autodiscover()` to `urls.py`. Further investigation required...

Answer (score 1):

Probably debug-toolbar's files aren't copied to `/home/chris/webapps/pyPolonel/static/`.

Don't you forget to call `manage.py collectstatic`? If you don't know what is it, read about [staticfiles app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/staticfiles/).

In delopment machine you can remove your `location /static/` and `location /media/` from configuration: when `settings.DEBUG == True` Django's runserver will serve static files.

In production always use `staticfiles`.

Comment: Correct. I have done this, in my static folder there is a 'debug_toolbar' folder with all the css/img/js in it and I can serve them up correctly.